# Linear gradient background repeats

Tags: css, background, repeating-linear-gradient

I made this linear-gradient background animation in css for my to-do list, but as I add more items to the list the website is scrollable and the background repeats making it look ugly.

I made some research about it and I saw `background-attachment: fixed;`, `background-repeat: no-repeat;` or sum like that but I can't get it to work, can someone help?

This is what it looks like

[image: 1]

Answer (score -1):

have you tried `background-size: cover;` or `background-size: auto;` ?
Find more here [mdn_web_docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)